# How to inject presenter to CustomTableViewCell as dependancy injection

Tags: swift

i'm learning Dependency Injection and created an app by MVP.

I could inject presenters for a few VCs in `AppDelegate` using storyboard.

But now I created `CustomTableViewCell` with `.xib` that has `UIButton` on the cell so that I would like to process the detail of it in the presenter file.

I tried to create `UINib(nibName~` in `AppDelegate` but when the presenter in `CustomTableViewCell` is called, it is `nil`.

I heard that an instance of a cell called in 'AppDelegate' is going to be disposed of. However I don't know any ways not to make `presenter` nil.

AppDelegate

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let mainTabVC = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTab", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! MainTabViewController
        let userDefault = UserDefault()
        let presenter = MainTabPresenter(view: mainTabVC, udManager: userDefault)
        mainTabVC.inject(presenter: presenter, userDefaultManager: userDefault)

        let addTabVC = UIStoryboard(name: "AddTab", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! AddTabViewController
        let alertHandller = AlertHandller()
        let addPresenter = AddTabPresenter(view: addTabVC, mainView: mainTabVC, alertHandller: alertHandller)
        addTabVC.inject(presenter: addPresenter)

        let settingTabVC = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingTab", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! SettingTabViewController
        let settingPresenter = SettingTabPresenter(view: settingTabVC)
        settingTabVC.inject(presenter: settingPresenter, alertHandller: alertHandller)

        let vcs = [mainTabVC, addTabVC, settingTabVC]

        let mainTabBar = UIStoryboard(name: "MainView", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! MainTabBarController
        mainTabBar.setViewControllers(vcs, animated: false)

        // no probs until here (inject functions work)

       // this is disposed??
        let listCell = UINib(nibName: "ListCell", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: ListCell.self, options: nil).first as! ListCell

       let cellPresenter = ListCellPresenter(view: mainTabVC)           
       listCell.inject(presenter: cellPresenter)

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = mainTabBar
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

VC that tableViewDataSource is written

```swift
class MainTabViewController: UIViewController {

    private let shared = Sharing.shared

    private var presenter: MainTabPresenterInput!
    private var userDefaultManager: UserDefaultManager!
    func inject(presenter: MainTabPresenterInput, userDefaultManager: UserDefaultManager) {
        self.presenter = presenter
        self.userDefaultManager = userDefaultManager
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableViewSetup()

    }

    func tableViewSetup(){
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListCell")
    }
}

extension MainTabViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shared.items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell") as! ListCell
        if let item = presenter.item(row: indexPath.row) {
            cell.configure(item: item)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

customTableViewCell

```swift
class ListCell: UITableViewCell {

    private let shared = Sharing.shared
    private var presenter: ListCellPresenterInput!

    func inject(presenter: ListCellPresenterInput) {
        self.presenter = presenter
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func favButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let row = self.tag
        switch shared.items[row].fav {
        case true:
            favButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favIconNon"), for: .normal)
        case false:
            favButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favIcon"), for: .normal)
        }
        presenter.countFavIcon(rowAt: row)　// this presenter is nil
    }

    func configure(item: Item) {
　　　　・・・
    }
}
```

cell presenter

```swift
protocol AddTabPresenterInput {
    func addButtonTapped(item item: Item?)
}

protocol AddTabPresenterOutput: AnyObject {
    func clearFields()
    func showAlert(alert: UIAlertController)
}

final class AddTabPresenter: AddTabPresenterInput {

    private weak var view: AddTabPresenterOutput!
    private weak var mainView: MainTabPresenterOutput!
    private weak var alertHandller: AlertHandllerProtocol!

    let shared = Sharing.shared

    init(view: AddTabPresenterOutput, mainView: MainTabPresenterOutput, alertHandller: AlertHandllerProtocol) {
        self.view = view
        self.mainView = mainView
        self.alertHandller = alertHandller
    }

    func addButtonTapped(item item: Item?) {
        print("called")
        mainView.updateView()
    }
}
```

How Can I solve the issue that `presenter` is nil?

Hopefully some of you would help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView uses reusable cells, you can find a lot of info in google, here is one of the articles

https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e

So creating an instance of UITableViewCell in AppDelegate you're doing nothing, it is immediately dispose

Create presenter

```
    // somewhere in your MainTabViewController
    let cellPresenter = ListCellPresenter(view: self)
```

To inject presenter you should use `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method

```
    // later in code
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell") as! ListCell
        cell.inject(presenter: cellPresenter)

        if let item = presenter.item(row: indexPath.row) {
            cell.configure(item: item)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
It is understandable but I should not create new mainTabVC as an instance here, right? Because the created instance is different from one displayed which is created in AppDelegate.
Apple does not recommend creating the shared instance of AppDelegate so that accessing MainTab created in AppDelegate is not good...
Hmm or my architecture that is creating the presenter of customCell is not right. What is the best solution to subdivide the job of CustomCell?

Comment: I've corrected the answer a bit, so now you see, that to create a presenter for a cell of course you should use current MainTabViewController. The architecture is ok. In my projects I create not one cellPresenter but for each cell, cause this presenter can change the view while it is on the screen.